# Java Dynamics CRM implementation

Tags: java, dynamics-crm

I tried to implement an Java based CRM implementation from the below reference link http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Consuming-CRM-REST-Service-ae24a15e,
 I did the steps provided from these blog. I added the proxy file generated in to my project. I'm in trouble to add new entity to CRM server, I tried the snippet below with my authentication details

```
public class client { 

    /** 
     * @param args 
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Authenticator a = new Authenticator() { 
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
                return (new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray())); 
            } 
        }; 
        // Sets the default Authenticator 
        Authenticator.setDefault(a); 
        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "jcifs"); 
        Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.domain", "domainname"); 
        Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.username", "username"); 
        Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.password", "password"); 
        Config.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.hostname","hostname"); 

        String[] arguments = { "http://crmserver/organization/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc/", "c:\\crm" }; 
        Generator.main(arguments); 
    } 
    MicrosoftCrmSdkDataServicesService service = new MicrosoftCrmSdkDataServicesService(); 
    Account act = new Account(); 
    String x = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); 
    act.setAccountId(x); 
    act.setName("Account from oData"); 
    try { 
       service.addEntity(act); 
    }  
    catch (Exception e)  
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 

}
```

while executing the snippet above I'm getting error like  **Bad Request (400) - Can't add entity to this entity set** Let me have any suggestion to fix these problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that a create call? Usually you don't set an id, you let CRM do it.

Comment: @JamesWood, even I tried after removing the act.SetAccountId(x) still rises the same error..

Comment: Is setName, setting a field on the entity? Or setting the name of the entity object?

Comment: What is this class MicrosoftCrmSdkDataServicesService, is it what you have written or coming from some jar?